# How to handle initialisation and events from external library?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am importing an external library (from a cdn; I know it's terrible) that needs to be initialised with some kind of config, and produces some kind of events.

Parent:

```
eventTrigerred = e => console.log(e)
...

<Component
   onEvent= {this.eventTrigerred}
/>
```

Child:

```
render() {
   const initiliseLibrary = () => {
       let config = {
           key: "XXX", // some key to initilise the library
           onLibraryEvent: this.props.onEvent  // the event I want to handle
       }  
       window.StrangeLibrary.init(config)
   } 

   return (
     <div id="library-area">
         {initialiseFrames()} // when initilised this library will render an elemnt here
     </div>
   );
}
```

The problem is that if in the parent the state changes, this reloads the child, and this result in the child being re-rendered, the event triggering again, and this infinitely loops.

I feel that I am doing somehting fundamentaly wrong, and I wish I did not have to use this library but I have to.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: I think that you should run the external library init in ComponentDidMount lifecycle method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The render function shouldn't create any side effect. Instead, put your initialisation code in `componentDidMount`, like so :

```
componentDidMount() {
   let config = {
       key: "XXX", // some key to initilise the library
       onLibraryEvent: this.props.onEvent  // the event I want to handle
   }  
   window.StrangeLibrary.init(config)
}
```

However, this code will be called again if the component will be remounted (but not if it's rendered again without remount, from a prop change, or a state change).

If it's still looping, you may want to lift the initialisation code in a parent component's `componentDidMount` that stays mounted all along.